# Splitting strings with scanner

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I am trying to split a string into two others with the Scanner in Java. It doesn't seem to be working. I can only find examples through Google where Scanner is used to read console input. I worked out the way I'm doing things from the manual for the Scanner and I'm not sure what I've got wrong.

```
String elem = "hello.there";
Scanner s = new Scanner(elem);
s.useDelimiter(".");
String first = s.next();
String second = s.next();
```

First and second are showing up blank, I'm not sure why.

Comment: `hasNext()` returns a boolean

Comment: as a side note, you don't have to use Scanner for this. split() will do it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to scape the period (`.`):

```
s.useDelimiter("\\.");
```

and then use [`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) which returns the next complete token, since [`hasNext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29) returns a `boolean` representinf if the scanner has another token in its input:

```
String first = s.next();
String second = s.next();
```

Comment: Thanks, I was actually using next, but I typed the code out of a larger method to make the question self-contained, and made a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TokenizeUsingScanner {


/**
 * This java sample code shows how to split
 * String value into tokens using
 * Scanner. This program tokenize
 * the input string base on the delimiter
 * set by calling the useDelimiter method
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String input = "hello.there";
    Scanner s = new Scanner(input);
    s.useDelimiter("\\.");
    while(s.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(s.next());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`String first = s.hasNext();` returns boolean so you can't asssign it to a string.

You need

```
String first = s.next();
```